# нужно сделать проверку на дату рождения,чтобы в нужный день программа поздровляла, но выдает ошибку

Tags: python

```
    import datetime
    dr = datetime.date(2004, 4, 22)
    a = datetime.date.today()
    m = a.month
    d = a.day
    if m in dr:
        if d in dr:
            print("с днем рождения")
    else:
        print("")


 if m in dr:
TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.date' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

Сравнивайте значения оператором `==`.

***Пример:***

```py
import datetime


dr = datetime.date(2004, 4, 22)

a = datetime.date.today()
m = a.month
d = a.day

if m == dr.month and d == dr.day:
    print("с днем рождения")
```